# I am trying to insert data from a JSON file into MYSQL using PHP but the data is not according to the format

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am currently stuck as the data (in a JSON file) is not inserting correctly into MYSQL according to my codes. I am using PHP to code this.

Raw data (in the JSON file) retrieved from transport website:

```
"d": [
       {

        "CreateDate": "/Date(1465439077603)/", 
        "Distance": 0, 
        "IncidentID": 13229765, 
        "Latitude": 1.3018178035280734, 
        "Longitude": 103.91129992706466, 
        "Message": "(9/6)10:23 Roadworks on ECP (towards Changi Airport) after Still Rd Sth Exit. Avoid lane 3.", 
        "Summary": null, 
        "Type": "Road Work", 
        "__metadata": {
            "type": "LTAModel.Incident", 
            "uri": "http://datamall.mytransport.sg/LTAoDataService.svc/IncidentSet(13229765)"
        }
    },
```

As you can see, "Message" contains 3 parts - time, date, message about the incident.

Thus, i am using preg_match to break the "message" apart:

```
           $message1 =preg_match("/^\(([0-9]+.+[0-9])\)([0-9]+.[0-9]+)\s(.+\s+.+)$/",$message,$messageArray);        

            if(isset($messageArray['1'])){
            $date = $messageArray['1'];
            echo $date. "<br/>";
            }
            if(isset($messageArray['2'])){
            $time = $messageArray['2'] ;
            echo $time. "<br/>";
            }
            if(isset($messageArray['3'])){
            $message3 = $messageArray['3'] ;
            echo $message3. "<br/>";    
            }
```

My codes to format the $date value as it is currenly 8/6 and I would like it to be :2016-06-08

```
                if(preg_replace('/\/\d/', '/3/2016', $date)){

                $find = array('/\/3/', '/\/4/', '/\/5/');
                $replace = array('/3/2016', '/4/2016', '/5/2016');
                $result = preg_replace($find, $replace, $date);

                echo $result. "<br/>";
```

Comment: Without the value of `$date`, this question is unanswerable. Hell, it's not even understandable at the moment.

Comment: the value of $date is 8/6 for now as the data retrieved are live streaming data

Comment: i've edited my post! do check it out to see if its clearer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
<?php
$input = '8/6';
$year = 2016;
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m', $input);
$dateAsIsoString = $date->format($year . '-m-d');

echo $dateAsIsoString;
```

If a year is always the current year, then you could use `format` like this:

```
$dateAsIsoString = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

because `DateTime::createFromFormat` automatically creates date object with current year, if it is not in the input string according to format.

Comment: not sure why isnt't it working tho :/ i have edited my post as well!

Comment: It working. I tested this code just right now on [php sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/14f3279b5c0eef3cb3dfc44aab7024e587cf0cdd)

Comment: You question is about converting date from one format to another (so I suggest to change the title). And it is answered here. If you want to ask another question about MySQL, please ask another question on SO.